# How to travel all paragraphs in a document with vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I open a document, and would like to travel and set all paragraghs with bold.

this is the code

```
for each par in activedocument.paragraphs:
    par.range.bold=true
next
```

After I run this code,I found paragraphs in textbox not be changed.

So,how to travel all paragraphs in a document with vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for the text boxes, because they are not paragraph objects.

```
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
  ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(shp.Name)).Select
  Selection.Font.Bold = True
Next
```

There are probably other ways too.

Answer (score 0):

That is the WRONG way to format a document. All you need do is format the relevant paragraph Styles with the bold attribute. For example:

```
ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleNormal).Font.Bold = True
```

Then it doesn't matter whether the content is in the document body, a header or footer, a footnote or endnote, or in a textbox in any of those ranges.